# How to send credentials (email/password) to Hotmail/Outlook signin page?

Tags: php, outlook, oauth-2.0, hotmail, import-contacts

I use this script (https://github.com/svetlozar/php-contacts-importer) to import user's contacts and allow the user to invite his contacts afterwards. I managed to have the yahoo and gmail import scripts working fine but I just can't get the Hotmail script to work. Sounds like they changed how they handle their signin page since this contact-importer script was developed. Can I send credentials to the new signin page using php and AJAX, if so how ?
Is there a way to send credentials to either the REST or javascript Hotmail APIs ?

Here is the direct link to the Hotmail.php file: https://github.com/svetlozar/php-contacts-importer/blob/master/Svetlozar.NET/Contacts/Hotmail.php

I see that somes sites are able to sign Hotmail/Outlook users through their own signin page, so I guess it is feasible.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CloudSponge PHP library works with the latest Hotmail APIs:

https://github.com/cloudsponge/cloudsponge-lib-php/

You can see the user experience here:

http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, have had a look and liked what I've seen through the demo. Might consider this as an alternative solution. But would prefer first to be able to use my own sign in page, any idea how I can acheive this with Hotmail ?