# How can send my login credentials to Hotmail via a script?

Tags: javascript, php, json, credentials, hotmail

I want to make a script to send my username and password to hotmail so I can be logged in without going through the login page. I don't want to use the "sign me in automatically" option for various reasons. I took a look at the source code to figure try to understand how Hotmail sends the credentials to the server for validation, but I cannot make heads from tails from the source code. Any help is appreciated.

I read a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690528/how-to-send-credentials-email-password-to-hotmail-outlook-signin-page) asking something very similar, but for different purpose--though the answer given is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you should be asking what hotmail accepts in the way of login requests, instead of starting with something and HOPING it'll work.

Comment: And I thought hotmal was sent to the eternal webmail-fields. I thought MS nowadays were maintaning live.com

Comment: you can't do this via php, simply because PHP works only on a server and does _nothing_ on your browser. To log into hotmail, you need to get a session with hotmail and a bunch of cookies set. PHP can't do that. Javascript can't do that either since it's not being run on the hotmail domain. So no.

Comment: There isn't a Hotmail API, so the short answer is no. The longer answer is, you can create an app to do this, but it will be violating a number of their agreements I imagine since you're using 3rd party tools to access their system at that point.

Comment: You can however make a page which with the press of a button makes a POST request to the hotmail servers, sending your password and username there and thus starting the login process. But... why would you want that?

Comment: @MarcB I will rephrase my question

Comment: @Tularis: No, you can't; that is a session fixation or CSRF attack.

Comment: @SLaks True, I had forgotten about that one. Still a no then :)

Comment: @Organiccat I'd like to make a script to automate it for use with Launchy.

Comment: ^ so you want to log in on your pc? Then yes you can probably do this with browser automation.

Comment: @user574632 Please elaborate. Perhaps if I look at the code and find the #id of the input boxes, I can automate it? I want to avoid a AutoIt or AutoHotkey approach (opening a webpage, clicking on the fields and sending keystrokes etc.) since in my experience it is not very reliable.

Comment: What tech do you want to use?? What must happen after you are logged in? The 'logged in' cookie will be browser specific, so i guess you need to control a specific browser (your primary one) etc

Comment: @user574632 I am using Windows 7 and I would prefer to do this with Firefox. I just want to log in as a one time log in. Basically I desire the same behavior as when you log into your hotmail account without clicking the sign me in automatically button.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

Comment: http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support

Comment: @user574632 I solved it by automating with Autoit and IE. I will post my code below. I appreciate the help though, if you make a good answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Using firefox I just create a bookmark called hm
in the "location" box paste in the code below,
when I load the hotmail page I just click on the bookmark.

```
javascript:%20document.getElementsByName('login').item(0).value='yourname@hotmail.co.uk';%20document.getElementsByName('passwd').item(0).value='yourpass';%20document.getElementsByName('SI').item(0).click();%20void(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to automate this through a browser**

Suggested by User574632. This is not the only solution, but it is an easier one.

I've come up with two solutions; one for use with Internet Explorer and the other for use with Firefox. Both solutions work with the browser to automate this task.

**Solution 1--Internet Explorer and AutoIt**

As it just so happens, AutoIt is very good at automating IE's functions. After reading a similar question on the AutoIt help forum [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/84716-login-to-hotmail-with-ieau3-udf/), I found most of what I needed. I just added support for command line parameters and voila. Here is the code written in AutoIt:

```
#include <IE.au3>
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

$oIE = _IECreate ("http://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=10&ct=1227208038&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fn%3D1521319951&id=64855")
_IELoadWait ($oIE)

$o_form = _IEFormGetObjByName ($oIE, "f1")
$o_login = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "login")
$o_password = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "passwd")
$o_signin = _IEFormElementGetObjByName ($o_form, "SI")

$username = $CmdLine[1] ; "YOUR_HOTMAIL_ADDRESS@hotmail.com"
$password = $CmdLine[2] ;"YOUR_PASSWORD"

_IEFormElementCheckBoxSelect ( $o_form, "remMe", "", 0)

_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_login, $username)
_IEFormElementSetValue ($o_password, $password)

_IEAction ($o_signin, "click")

WinSetState ( "Internet", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE )
```

Note that this was not written by me, I only modified it to accept command line parameters.

After compiling, usage is: `Executable.exe "EmailAddress@hotmail.com" "Password"`

**Solution 2--Firefox and iMacros**

1. Install iMacros here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/
2. Open iMacros and create a marco
3. Insert the following script, replacing the email address and password with your own:

> 

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1391468097&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx&lc=1033&id=64855&mkt=en-us&cbcxt=mai&snsc=1&bk=1391468099&uaid=9d4d29da2c304ed581e61d3fc51be1eb
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=NAME:f1 ATTR=ID:i0116 CONTENT=EMAILADDRESS@hotmail.com
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:f1 ATTR=ID:i0118 CONTENT=PASSWORD
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f1 ATTR=ID:idSIButton9
```

Then name the macro as "HotmailLogin.iim"

All you need to do to use it is create a shortcut with command line parameters like this:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros://run/?m=HotmailLogon.iim`

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible without actually having your browser visit the hotmail.com login page, for various reasons:

1. You can not use PHP to do this, since PHP is fully serverside and logging in a server has absolutely no effect on you (the client). It would log itself in, not you.
2. You can also not use javascript to set any type of cookie / session for hotmail.com from a different domain (that is not hotmail.com) due to security preventions which make sure you can't set a cookie for domain A from a page on domain B.
3. Making a POST request from a different domain is also not allowed by the HTTP protocol, so no here as well. Your browser will block any POST request from a page at A.com trying to post to server B.com
4. Hotmail forces you to first go to their login page to get a special cookie with a session-ID. Only if this special session-ID is sent back with the POST request will hotmail allow the request to go through. So you still have to get the sessionID first.

So in short: no.

Comment: I believe more research needs to go into this answer. IMHO it is inaccurate to say that Hotmail only accepts post requests originating from their own server or domain because, if not with a POST request from your browser, how else would your computer send hotmail the credentials required for logging in? If you improve your answer, or can provide more information I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Why inaccurate? Browsers make requests to servers, then display the result. The resulting page (from the hotmail.com domain) can contain a form which when submitted makes another POST request to that same domain (hotmail.com). It can NOT make a POST request to a different server (eg. google.com) unless the page in question actually came from google.com. This is handled by the browser. Besides that, Hotmail has a ton of protection to make sure that you first visit their login page (where they set a session-cookie) and by sending that sessionID back will they allow the login to continue.

Comment: @Klik is this better?

Comment: Yes, this is better description. Personally, I don't like answers that say something is not possible since anything *is* technically possible, though the method might be difficult. According to your own description, you need to get the sessionID first, which could be done by emulating a browser. This is beyond my capabilities, but it *is* possible.